# Write current time plus 5 minutes in MySql from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Helllo, I have a query that writes some data to the database

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO PVS (time_ended) 
VALUES (now())", $db_conx) 
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_query ("UPDATE PVS SET break = now() WHERE id = '$id'", $db_conx)
or die (mysql_error());
```

What I want is to store current time + 5 minutes instead of now() for time_ended, and current time + 15 seconds instead of now() for break

Can someone show me the trick?
Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try like this

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO PVS (time_ended) 
VALUES ((now() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE))", $db_conx) 
or die (mysql_error());
```

and

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE PVS SET break = (now() + INTERVAL 5 SECOND) WHERE id = '$id'", $db_conx)
or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 5):

this `DATE_ADD()` help:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 SECOND);
```

**store current time + 5 minutes instead of now() for time_ended**

```
INSERT INTO PVS (time_ended) VALUES (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

**current time + 15 sec**

```
UPDATE PVS SET break = DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 15 SECOND) WHERE id = '$id'
```

**and all possible INTERVAL**

you can find at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp